# SelectOneMenu with Delete link

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I am wondering is there a way i can add delete() in the select one menu, so that the user either can select one from the menu or delete the record right from there itself. So far i have normal select one menu, i have a method called "#{statusReport.deleteTieckt}" method. I just wondering how to add that to the below select one menu.

```
<ice:selectOneMenu value="#{statusReport.projectDetID}"
                        style="width: 350px;" partialSubmit="true"
                        onchange="this.form.submit()" immediate="true"
                        valueChangeListener="#{statusReport.retrieveReport}">
                            <f:ajax disabled="true"></f:ajax>

                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{statusReport.listOfProjectDetail}"
                            var="projectBO"
                            itemLabel="#{projectBO.projectDtObj.pname}        #{projectBO.startDate}   -    #{projectBO.endDate}"
                            itemValue="#{projectBO.pdetailId}" noSelectionValue="true" />
                    </ice:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: You should probably have two separate comboboxes for that. I mean how does one come to know if the user's intention was to select or delete.

Comment: if you open the selectonemenu it shoud appear as "project_name : Delete". Where delete is a anchor which when click should remove it from the list.